# PL/SQL cursors and records

Tags: plsql, cursors, record

I am a new to Pl/sql and I need to learn to write simple pl/sql scripts.
Is there any difference between cursors and records in PL/sql?
So far I find them both similar.

Comment: Ok after a bit of research I have figured it out. 
Cursors are just memory created By SQL when a DML statement is fired. 
You could have implicit or explicit cursors. 
Where as records are datatypes holding data of different kinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new to PL SQL here, and wanted to help with what i know...

A record is similar to a table row, can hold one value for each column at a time. 
cursors are like "tables" they may hold multiple rows (records if you will).

this is one way how you can declare a record:

```
DECLARE
TYPE myRecType
IS
RECORD
(
  [COLUMN NAME] [DATA TYPE],
  .
  ..
  );
```

Cursors can be explicit or implicit.
Implicit cursors are created each time you run a query, and have some attributes that may give you an idea of what happened after your query is ran.
e.g.

```
SQL%FOUND will return either TRUE or FALSE if your DML statement affects at least 1 record.

SQL%ROWCOUNT will return the number of rows afected by your DML statement...
```

Explicit cursors on the other hand, are needed for advanced data manipulation, you can create your own cursor by supplying a query, and you can iterate through that cursor to do more data manipulations

simple syntax to declare a cursor with a SELECT query and loop through the results:

```
Declare
  cursor Mycursor is 
    SELECT 
      ColA,
      ColB,
      Colc
    FROM MyTable;
Begin

   -- Iterate using a for loop
  for X in Mycursor loop
    --print Mycursor.ColA
    -- do whatever you want to do with your data
  end loop;
end;
```